# ASP.NET 5 dependency injection outside of Controllers and Views

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Each tutorial or example that I've found for using DI in ASP.NET 5 only shows how it works with Controllers and Razor Views.  I need to use DI for other classes but don't know the proper way to resolve types and provide an instance.  Right now I have an instance of a `HackyDependencyResolver` that everything must reference in order to get the proper instances.  I want to either access ASP.NET's service resolver or follow some other best-practice for resolving dependencies.

For example if I have

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public SomeClass(IUseMe useMe)
  {
  }
}
```

which is not an ASP.NET MVC Controller.  I need a pattern for resolving a correct instance for `IUseMe` when `SomeClass` is created.  Certainly I can make my own global factory, but is that the best way?

Comment: What are the other classes you want to inject?

Comment: @3dd I updated the question with an example of what I want to do.  Thanks.

Comment: SomeClass will need to be injected into the `Controller` for this too work, see the `Controller` class is constructed using the DI and all it's dependencies are/should be satisfied by the DI

Comment: @3dd and I'm asking how to instantiate `SomeClass` outside of any Controller.  Forget Controllers ... ASP.NET5 handles that well.  How do I resolve `IUseMe` so that I'm not dependent on a particular implementation?

Comment: You load `IUseMe` into the container with some class satisfying it and then ask the container to resolve the instance.  In the case of MVC `Controllers` the container is configured to resolve them and their dependancies

Comment: @3dd _ask the container to resolve the instance_ ... this is where I need help. How do I access the container?  I have not found how to do this in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84604/discussion-between-3dd-and-jltrem).

Comment: if you are using the default DI in your startup.cs add services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUseMe, YourClassThatImplementsIUseMe>());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DI has nothing to do with asp.net, controllers or views. In the end all are classes. Considering that an action is an entrypoint in your app, any service you need there should be injected, The service itself has some dependencies and those will be injected automatically by the DI Container when it instantiates the controller.

All you have to do is to define your *services* (not every object needs injected deps) then register those services into the Di Container.

> How do I resolve IUseMe so that I'm not dependent on a particular implementation?

You don't. The Di Container does that based on configuration, when the controller is instantiated. Everything has a flow, you don't just pick classes out of thin air and say "I want this created by the Di container". OK you could, but it would be the wrong approach.

The whole point of using a DI Container is not to care about instantiating services. The framework takes care of integrating with the container, your only job is to define the classes properly and to configure the container .